# #1064 -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, error-handling, create-table

I'm new to `PHP` and `MySQL` and ran into a little trouble with a learning project I'm working on.

Whenever I try to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
category varchar(50) NOT NULL,
amount double(10) NOT NULL,
type varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
notes varchar(512),
receipt int(10),
)
```

I get the following error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') NOT NULL, type varchar(6) NOT NULL, notes varchar(512),
>   receipt int(10), ' at line 6**

Here is some info on what I'm working with

1. Server type: MySQL
2. Server version: 5.5.32 - MySQL Community Server(GPL)
3. phpMyAdmin: 4.0.4.1, latest stable version: 4.1.7

I've spent a day knocking my head against the wall over this and now I think its time to ask for help.I was wondering if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have a comma at the end of the `receipt` line.

Answer (score 17):

Remove the comma

`receipt int(10),`

And also `AUTO INCREMENT` should be a **KEY**

`double` datatype also requires the precision of decimal places so right syntax is `double(10,2)`

Comment: This answer is partly correct. It did not answer on what the error message returned.

Comment: double datatype also requires the precision of decimal places so right syntax is double(10,2)

Answer (score 9):

One obvious thing is that you will have to remove the comma here

```
receipt int(10),
```

but the actual problem is because of the line

```
amount double(10) NOT NULL,
```

change it to

```
amount double NOT NULL,
```

Comment: This worked for me. Why shouldn't I give a length to a double?

Comment: It has been years since you asked this, but for posterity, the reason this works is that the syntax you used to give length to a double was wrong. You need to give the length in the format double(10, 2), where 2 is the number of decimal places. Removing the length just made it use the default.

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, the word 'type' is a Reserved Word.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

DOUBLE(10) precision definitions need a total number of digits, as well as a total number of digits after the decimal:

DOUBLE(10,8)
would make be ten total digits, with 8 allowed after the decimal.

Also, you'll need to specify your id column as a key :

```
CREATE TABLE transactions( 
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
location varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
description varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
category varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
amount double(10,9) NOT NULL, 
type varchar(6) NOT NULL,  
notes varchar(512), 
receipt int(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(id) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem before, the reason behind that for me was the last comma in the schema definition should be deleted if there's no extra columns would be added.

```
CREATE TABLE users 
    (
         id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
         email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
         password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    // this comma should be deleted
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Rule 1: You can not add a new table without specifying the `primary key` constraint[not a good practice if you create it somehow].
So the code:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions( 
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
location varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
description varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
category varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
amount double(10,9) NOT NULL, 
type varchar(6) NOT NULL,  
notes varchar(512), 
receipt int(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Rule 2: You are not allowed to use the keywords(words with predefined meaning) as a field name.
Here **type** is something like that is used(commonly used with **Join Types**).
So the code:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions( 
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
location varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
description varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
category varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
amount double(10,9) NOT NULL, 
transaction_type varchar(6) NOT NULL,  
notes varchar(512), 
receipt int(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Now you please try with this code.
First check it in your database user interface(I am running HeidiSQL, or you can try it in your xampp/wamp server also)and make sure this code works. Now delete the table from your db and execute the code in your program.
Thank You.