# mysql insert query is syntactically correct but showing errors

Tags: mysql

`INSERT INTO AlbumSongs (albumId,songId,rank) VALUES ("a3092aee5d397fef823656c31cd131e0","DPEUD1tm1RWp",9)`

I tried to execute this query in my mysql database.
but it shows this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank) VALUES ("a3092aee5d397fef823656c31cd131e0","DPEUD1tm1RWp",9)' at line 1`

my mysql server version   ```Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))``

What is wrong with this query? how can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1064 -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798464/1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-t)

Comment: no.this doesn't answer my question..

Answer (score 1):

`rank` is a function in MySQL, so the query engine is expecting to see something like:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY {column} ORDER BY {column})
```

If you really *must* use this name for the column, consider putting all of your column names in back ticks like so:

```
INSERT INTO `AlbumSongs` (`albumId`, `songId`, `rank`)
VALUES ('a3092aee5d397fef823656c31cd131e0', 'DPEUD1tm1RWp', 9);
```

> **Note:** Table names can also be wrapped the same way, and the strings are single-quoted rather than double quoted.

Ideally all table and column names should be defined like this when writing queries.

Comment: thanks..this worked for me